# how can i add multilangues part in a web site

Tags: php, laravel, multilingual

Website is English by default and I want when I app locale is English doesn't have an effect on my routes. and I want my routes to be like this :

for English be like this:

```
https://example.com/about
```

for Arabic be like this

```
https://example.com/ar/about
```

I use a middleware (setlocale) and I want to validate the first segment or anything that make a specific langue of the site it's important to Validate by (where...) the helper function in the route I think logic must be like this if segment one be null langue must be " en " and don't show in the URL if segment one be " ar " langue must be " ar " I did it somewhere and I keep it on : [Github](https://github.com/pouyabh/Multi-Language)

Answer (score 1):

In route file add [prefix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes) for all route and put multi-language middleware.

```
Route::prefix('{lang}')->group(function ($lang) {
    // Do something with lang param
    Route::get('/about', function () use ($lang) {
        // Matches The "/{lang}/about" URL
        echo $lang;
    });
})->middleware('setlocale'); // Your local middleware
```